# Install unix program without internet access

Tags: rhel, node.js, npm

I have a red hat server (server 1) which does not have access to internet. I also have another another red hat server (server 2) which DOES have access to internet and it can also access server 1.

I need to install programs on server 1. In this case it is about a node module called pm2. I am not sure how this can be done. Should I install the module on server 2 and then upload it to the server 1? Or generally: what is the approach to take in this situation?

Comment: download and transfer the necessary rpms to server1, install them with yum/rpm

Comment: or internal mirror/pulp

Comment: How can you access server 1?

Answer (score 1):

Download the package (should end with .rpm) to server 2, then scp the file over to server 1 and run `rpm -Uvh package.rpm` as root.

Answer (score 0):

**`node`** modules do not necessarily come packaged in rpms.  It can — and does — read from the network (bypassing the rpm system).  You would use the **`node`** package manager (**`npm`**) to install into a tarball which you could copy to the non-networked machine, and *untar* there.

The [webpage for `pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) indicates that it would be installed (using the network) with `npm`, giving as example

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

You could use `npm pack` to make a tarball from that point.  The answer by [tsturzl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034031/4518274) in [node.js: Installing a tar.gz on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033538/installing-a-tar-gz-on-linux) explains it well enough: decide where to put it on the target machine and untar there.

Further reading:

- [**`npm-install`**: Install a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> This command installs a package, and any packages that it depends on. If the package has a shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that. See [npm-shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap).

- [**`npm-pack`** : Create a tarball from a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack)
- [npm issues #1349 - How can I install packages with all dependencies offline?](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1349) , has comment (and elaboration):

  > List the dependencies in `bundledDependencies` in your `package.json`, and then run **`npm pack`** to create a tarball. Get that over to the other machine, adn either npm install *`<tarball>`*, or just crack it open manually.
- [A Beginner’s Guide to npm — the Node Package Manager](https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/)